# How to create custom drop down field on checkout page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, template, drop-downs

How to create **custom field** on **checkout billing address** in magento2?

I want simple drop down on checkout page just we can use for admin order and this field also saves in the database table like order table and  b/c I will use in advertisement.

Comment: Do you need the dropdown in backend or in frontend checkout?

Answer (score 2):

For Frontend:

In layout file  checkout_index_index call the template file which has your dropdown html code.it will be displayed on you checkout page.

Code:
file name has checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
             <block class="Test\CommunityCommerce\Block\Charity\Charity" name="charity_charity" after="checkout.cart.coupon" template="Sundial_CommunityCommerce::checkout/cart/charity.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

In Template file consists  :

file name has charity.phtml

```
    <div class="content" data-role="content" aria-labelledby="block-charity-heading">
        <form id="charity-form"
              action="#"
              method="post"
              value="0" />
            <?php //echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="control">
                         <select id="charity_id" name="charity_id">                     
                                <option value="test1">test1</option>
                                <option value="test2">test2</option>
                          </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </form>         
    </div>      
</div>
```

Create column in quote table and sales table using setup scripts using "InstallSchema" it will create  column into table.

After that using sales_convert_quote and fieldset.xml it will move to quote value to sales table

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to obtain the customer data is to ask customers through custom fields at the checkout page are -

Create a new module with this folder structure. For instance, I have created a module with Ecomsolver as Vendor name and Customcheck as the module name.

1. The path will be as follows

> app/code/Ecomsolver/Customcheck

2. In this create a file `registration.php` with the following code

   ```
   <?php     
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
   'Ecomsolver_Customcheck',
   __DIR__
    );
   ```
3. Now create a folder with name “etc” in Customcheck. Then create XML file in this. Path of XML file will be

> app/code/Ecomsolver/Customcheck/etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Ecomsolver_Customcheck" setup_version="1.0.0">
    <sequence>
      <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
    </sequence> 
  </module>
</config>
```

4. Now create a folder with name “`frontend`”. Place a XML file in it. Path of XML file will be

> app/code/Ecomsolver/Customcheck/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd>
  <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
    <plugin name="add_custom_field_checkout_form" type="Ecomsolver\Customcheck\Model\Plugin\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="100"/>
  </type>
</config>
```

5. Create a folder with name “Model”. Again create a folder in it Plugin -> Checkout. In this create a file. The path of a file will be

> Model/Plugin/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php

```
<?php
  namespace Ecomsolver\Customcheck\Model\Plugin\Checkout;
  class LayoutProcessor
  {
    public function afterProcess
    (
      \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,array $jsLayout
    )
    {
      $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
      ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['custom_field'] =
      ['component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract','config' => 
      [
        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
        'options' => [],
        'id' => 'custom-field'
      ],
        'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.custom_field',
        'label' => 'Password',
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'visible' => true,
        'validation' => [],
        'sortOrder' => 250,
        'id' => 'custom-field'
      ];
      $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
      ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['custom_field2'] =
      [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract','config' =>
        [
          'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
          'template' => 'ui/form/field',
          'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
          'options' => [],
          'id' => 'custom-field2'
        ],
        'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.custom_field2',
        'label' => 'Confirm Password',
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'visible' => true,
        'validation' => [],
        'sortOrder' => 260,
        'id' => 'custom-field2'
      ];
      $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
      ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['custom_field3'] =
      [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
        'config' =>
        [
          'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
          'template' => 'ui/form/field',
          'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/checkbox',
          'options' => [],
          'id' => 'custom-field3'
        ],
        'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.custom_field3',
        'label' => 'Create Account',
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'visible' => true,
        'checked' => false,
        'validation' => [],
        'sortOrder' => 250,
        'id' => 'custom-field3'
      ];
  return $jsLayout;
  } 
}
```